# Can I get other metric values using model history file already ran though model.fit()?

Tags: keras

I thought that in the model history file, there were all information such as y_pred, y_true values as model trains, so that I thoguth even if I add other metrics which I customaized, I could reuse the history file not running model.fit() again. Is this possible?

Comment: I dont think history object stores your data. No model file will ever store data rather it will store architecture, weights and biases.

Comment: No, History objects don't contain your data.